# F# - Algorithm and strings

Tags: algorithm, f#

Let's says I have a string of a length N that contains only 0 or 1. I want to split that string in multiples strings and each string should contains only one digit.

Example:

> 00011010111

Should be split into:

> - 000
> - 11
> - 0
> - 1
> - 0
> - 111

The only solution I can think of if using a for loop with a string builder (Written in pseudo code below, more c# like sorry):

```
 result = new list<string>
 tmpChar = ""
 tmpString = ""
 for each character c in MyString
     if tmpchar != c
         if tmpsString != ""
             result.add tmpString
             tmpString = ""
         endIf
         tmpchar = c
     endIf
     tmpString += tmpChar
 endFor
```

Do you have any other solution and maybe a clever solution that use a more functional approach?

Comment: There seems to be an error in your example.

Comment: indeed, I correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Seq.fold (fun (acc:(string list)) x ->
          match acc with
          | y::rst when y.StartsWith(string x) -> (string x) + y::rst
          | _ -> (string x)::acc)
        []
        "00011010111"
```

Comment: As written, the chunks are in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

I think Seq.scan would be a good fit for this, this is a very procedural problem in nature, preserving the order like that. But here is code that I believe does what you are asking.

```
"00011010111"
|> Seq.scan (fun (s, i) x ->
    match s with
    | Some p when p = x -> Some x, i
    | _ -> Some x, i + 1 ) (None, 0)
|> Seq.countBy id
|> Seq.choose (function 
| (Some t, _), n -> Some(t, n)
| _ -> None )
|> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
let result = 
  let rec groupWhileSame xs result =
    match xs with 
    | a when a |> Seq.isEmpty -> result
    | _ -> 
      let head = xs |> Seq.head
      let str = xs |> Seq.takeWhile ((=) head)
      let rest = xs |> Seq.skipWhile ((=) head)
      groupWhileSame rest (Seq.append result [str])

  groupWhileSame (myStr) []
```

Comment: Do you think an if/then/else would be more natural than a match here?

Comment: I suspect the answer to that is very opinionated, and would differ from team to team.  if/then/else would certainly be less code here.  I'm guessing I reached for a match statement first since usually recursive collection functions are done with lists, and the match would be very elegant for a list.  It did get a bit ugly with Seq there...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this function (which is generic):

```
let chunk s =
if Seq.isEmpty s then []
else
    let rec chunk items chunks =
        if Seq.isEmpty items then chunks
        else             
            let chunks' =
                match chunks with
                | [] -> [(Seq.head items, 1)]
                | x::xs ->               
                    let c,n = x in let c' = Seq.head items in
                    if c = c' then (c, n + 1) :: xs else (c', 1) :: x :: xs

            chunk (Seq.tail items) chunks'

    chunk s [] |> List.rev
```

It returns a list of tuples, where each tuple represents an item and its repetitions.

So

```
"00011010111" |> Seq.toList |> chunk
```

actually returns

```
[('0', 3); ('1', 2); ('0', 1); ('1', 1); ('0', 1); ('1', 3)]
```

Basically, we're doing [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) (which is admittedly a bit wasteful in the case of your example string).

To get the list of strings that you want, we use code like following:

```
"00011010111" 
|> Seq.toList 
|> chunk 
|> List.map (fun x -> let c,n = x in new string(c, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of OP's proposal with light syntax:

```
let chunk (s: string) =
  let result = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>()
  let mutable tmpChar = ""
  let mutable tmpString = ""
  for c in s do
    if tmpChar <> string c then
      if tmpString <> "" then
        result.Add tmpString
        tmpString <- ""
      tmpChar <- string c
    tmpString <- tmpString + tmpChar
  result.Add tmpString
  result
```

No attempt was made to follow a functional style.